# Is it possible to control the whole Gnome desktop with vi-like commands?

Tags: vim, emacs, vi, gnome, readline

I know with readline you can use emacs or vi commands to edit the input of several
interactive text programs. I wonder if there exists such a similar facility to control
the whole desktop in Gnome or in any other desktop environment.

Maybe it could be a program that intercepts keystrokes and process them in the way vi does, translating sequences of characters to desktop commands and delivering to the active window only the text that is writen in insert mode.

Do you know some tool like that?

Comment: No, I don't know of such a mechanism. What kind of commands would you like to port? Window navigation? Text input? Anyway, I think that this questions belongs to superuser.

Answer (score 3):

Have a try of [Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) or [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org)! These two are the most famous tiling windows managers that use vi-like keybindings to navigate the windows.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/). It is possible to control it completely from keyboard.